# JSoup displaying an empty TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, jsoup

I am trying to display some text(title and body) from URL using **JSoup** in `TextView` positioned inside a `Fragment`. I am testing this on my device. No app crashes. However, the `TextView` is blank. Am I missing something?

I tried using this code inside the fragment

```
Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://qz.com/719792/india-is-slowly-cleaving-into-two-countries-the-old-and-the-young/").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (doc != null) {
        titleFWP.setText(doc.title());   //display title
        contentFWP.setText(doc.getElementsByTag("body").text());   //display body
    }
```

*titleFWP*, *contentFWP* are the two textViews injected using Butterknife

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code on a jave console and every thing looks OK, so I suspect that you have to set the `userAgent` string to match non-mobile browser:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://qz.com/719792/india-is-slowly-cleaving-into-two-countries-the-old-and-the-young/")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0")        
        .get();
```

Some servers return different pages to different browsers. Since you don't set the `userAgent` string by yourself, the request is being sent with some default string, and you get a different page then you expect.

**EDIT:** The `userAgent` string should be of course between double quotes...

Comment: I am sorry. But the textView still remains blank. No crashes nothing. Does this has anything to do with Async (because the code currently runs in UI thread)?

Comment: 1. Running in UI thread - usually the app crashes if you block the UI for few seconds, so you beetter move it to AsyncTask anyway. 2. Check if the `get` requests returns something. Try this - `if (doc != null) Log.d("Myapp", doc.html()); else Log.d("Myapp", "null");` Now you can read the Logcat and pinpoint the problem.